# OpenGl SuperBible implementing camera Pitch (Looking up and down)

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rotation, pitch

I'm having some trouble implementing looking up and down using the mouse in openGl, I can get the camera to rotate about the x-axis, however when i move forward, i starting going up at an angle, this would be great if i was doing a free moving camera, however I simply want to be able to look side to side and up and down, etc.

I've included my core functions.

```
// SphereWorld.cpp
// OpenGL SuperBible
// New and improved (performance) sphere world
// Program by Richard S. Wright Jr.

#include <GLTools.h>
#include <GLShaderManager.h>
#include <GLFrustum.h>
#include <GLBatch.h>
#include <GLFrame.h>
#include <GLMatrixStack.h>
#include <GLGeometryTransform.h>
#include <StopWatch.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <glut/glut.h>
#else
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#define NUM_SPHERES 50
GLFrame spheres[NUM_SPHERES];

int nWindowWidth = 800;
int nWindowHalfWidth = nWindowWidth/2;
int nWindowHeight = 600;
int nWindowHalfHeight = nWindowHeight/2;


GLShaderManager     shaderManager;          // Shader Manager
GLMatrixStack       modelViewMatrix;        // Modelview Matrix
GLMatrixStack       projectionMatrix;       // Projection Matrix
GLFrustum           viewFrustum;            // View Frustum
GLGeometryTransform transformPipeline;      // Geometry Transform Pipeline

GLTriangleBatch     torusBatch;
GLBatch             floorBatch;
GLBatch             grayFloorBatch;
GLTriangleBatch     sphereBatch;
GLFrame             cameraFrame;

GLfloat nCurrentMouseX = 0.0f;
GLfloat nCurrentMouseY = 0.0f;
float m_fAngular = 0.0f;
float _fXCameraAngRot = 0.0f;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This function does any needed initialization on the rendering
// context. 
void SetupRC()
    {
    // Initialze Shader Manager
    shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glLineWidth(2.5f);
    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // This makes a torus
    gltMakeTorus(torusBatch, 0.4f, 0.15f, 30, 30);

    // This make a sphere
    gltMakeSphere(sphereBatch, 0.1f, 26, 13);

    floorBatch.Begin(GL_LINES, 324);
    for(GLfloat x = -20.0; x <= 20.0f; x+= 0.5) 
    {
        floorBatch.Vertex3f(x, -0.55f, 20.0f);
        floorBatch.Vertex3f(x, -0.55f, -20.0f);

        floorBatch.Vertex3f(20.0f, -0.55f, x);
        floorBatch.Vertex3f(-20.0f, -0.55f, x);
    }
    floorBatch.End();    

    grayFloorBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,4);
    grayFloorBatch.Vertex3f(-20.0f, -.56f,-20.0f);
    grayFloorBatch.Vertex3f(20.0f, -.56f,-20.0f);
    grayFloorBatch.Vertex3f(-20.0f, -.56f,20.0f);
    grayFloorBatch.Vertex3f(20.0f, -.56f,20.0f);
    grayFloorBatch.End();

    // Randomly place the spheres
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_SPHERES; i++) {
        GLfloat x = ((GLfloat)((rand() % 400) - 200) * 0.1f);
        GLfloat z = ((GLfloat)((rand() % 400) - 200) * 0.1f);
        spheres[i].SetOrigin(x, 0.0f, z);
        }
    }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Screen changes size or is initialized
void ChangeSize(int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    nWindowWidth = nWidth;
    nWindowHeight = nHeight;
    nWindowHalfWidth = nWindowWidth/2;
    nWindowHalfHeight = nWindowHeight/2;
    glViewport(0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);

    // Create the projection matrix, and load it on the projection matrix stack
    viewFrustum.SetPerspective(35.0f, float(nWidth)/float(nHeight), 1.0f, 100.0f);
    projectionMatrix.LoadMatrix(viewFrustum.GetProjectionMatrix());

    // Set the transformation pipeline to use the two matrix stacks 
    transformPipeline.SetMatrixStacks(modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix);
}


// Called to draw scene
void RenderScene(void)
{
    // Color values
    //static GLfloat vFloorColor[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    static GLfloat vFloorColor[] = { (85.0f/255.0f), (186.0f/255.0f), (242.0f/255.0f), 1.0f};
    static GLfloat vgrayFloorColor[] = { (100.0f/255.0f), (98.0f/255.0f), (111.0f/255.0f), 1.0f};
    static GLfloat vTorusColor[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    static GLfloat vSphereColor[] = { (160.0f/255.0f), (41.0f/255.0f), (35.0f/255.0f), 1.0f };

    // Time Based animation
    static CStopWatch   rotTimer;
    float yRot = rotTimer.GetElapsedSeconds() * 60.0f;
    cameraFrame.RotateWorld(-m_fAngular, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    //cameraFrame.RotateWorld(_fXCameraAngRot,1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Clear the color and depth buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    // Save the current modelview matrix (the identity matrix)
    modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix();   

        M3DMatrix44f mCamera;
        cameraFrame.GetCameraMatrix(mCamera);
        modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix(mCamera);

            // Draw the ground
            shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT,transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(),vFloorColor); 
            floorBatch.Draw();    
            shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT,transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vgrayFloorColor);    
            grayFloorBatch.Draw();

            for(int i = 0; i < NUM_SPHERES; i++) 
            {
                modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix();
                modelViewMatrix.MultMatrix(spheres[i]);
                shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(),vSphereColor);
                sphereBatch.Draw();
                modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();
            }

            // Draw the spinning Torus
            modelViewMatrix.Translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.5f);

            // Save the Translation
            modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix();
                // Apply a rotation and draw the torus
                modelViewMatrix.Rotate(yRot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
                shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(),vTorusColor);
                torusBatch.Draw();
            modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix(); // "Erase" the Rotation from before

            // Apply another rotation, followed by a translation, then draw the sphere
            modelViewMatrix.Rotate(yRot * -2.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            modelViewMatrix.Translate(0.8f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vSphereColor);
            sphereBatch.Draw();

            modelViewMatrix.Rotate(_fXCameraAngRot, 1.0,0,0);
        // Restore the previous modleview matrix (the identity matrix)
            //modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();
        modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();
    modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();  
    // Do the buffer Swap
    glutSwapBuffers();

    // Tell GLUT to do it again
    glutPostRedisplay();
}


// Respond to arrow keys by moving the camera frame of reference
void SpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y)
{
    float linear = 0.1f;
    float angular = float(m3dDegToRad(5.0f));

    if(key == GLUT_KEY_UP)
        cameraFrame.MoveForward(linear);

    if(key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
        cameraFrame.MoveForward(-linear);

    if(key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
        cameraFrame.RotateWorld(angular, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    if(key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
        cameraFrame.RotateWorld(-angular, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);        
}

void KeyPress(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    float linear = 0.1f;

    if(key == 'W' || key == 'w' )
        cameraFrame.MoveForward(linear);

    if(key == 'S' || key == 's')
        cameraFrame.MoveForward(-linear);

    if(key == 'A' || key == 'a')
        cameraFrame.MoveRight(linear);

    if(key == 'D' || key == 'd')
        cameraFrame.MoveRight(-linear);
}

void MouseMove(int x, int y)
{
    GLfloat nXDelta = x-nWindowHalfWidth;

    if(nXDelta >= -50 && nXDelta <= 50)
    {
        nXDelta = 0.0f;
    }

    GLfloat yRot = nXDelta * .005;// * .5f;

    m_fAngular = float(m3dDegToRad(yRot));

    GLfloat nYDelta = y - nWindowHalfHeight;

    if(nYDelta >= -25 && nYDelta <= 25)
    {
        nYDelta = 0.0f;
    }

    GLfloat xRot = nYDelta;//  * .005;
    _fXCameraAngRot = float(m3dDegToRad(xRot));

    printf("x value is: %d - xdelta is %1.00f xRot is %f\n", x, nXDelta, _fXCameraAngRot);

    //cameraFrame.RotateLocalX(float(m3dDegToRad(xRot)));
    //cameraFrame.RotateLocal(float(m3dDegToRad(xRot)),1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(nWindowWidth,nWindowHeight);

    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL SphereWorld");
    glutKeyboardFunc(KeyPress);
    glutSpecialFunc(SpecialKeys);
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(MouseMove); 

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        return 1;
    }


    SetupRC();
    glutMainLoop();    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the implementation of GLFrame here:

http://code.google.com/p/oglsuperbible5/source/browse/trunk/Src/GLTools/include/GLFrame.h?r=160

It looks like you should be able to move forwards the way you want by calling `cameraFrame.TranslateWorld`.

The easiest way is probably to get the forward vector using `GetForwardVector`, flatten it into the x-z plane by zeroing out its `y` component, scale it to the right length and translate by it using `TranslateWorld`. YMMV :)